# select all data from excel and insert data to new excel file using c# oledb

Tags: c#

I would like to select all data from a sheet in excel and then create new excel file using c# code then insert that data into new excel file that created. I have code select data from excel below but I know how to write code create new excel file and insert data that I have select to new excel.

```
   public DataTable bindExcel(string filename, string filetype, string path)
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    if (filename != "")
    {
        string connString = "";

        switch (filetype)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }
        connString = String.Format(connString, path, "Yes");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = "";
        SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        string query = "SELECT * From [" + "DATA$" + "]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Plan");
        tbl = ds.Tables["Plan"];

        da.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
    return tbl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got all this explained in this two links: [Create Excel File](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm) and [Insert data in Excel using oledb](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb-insert.htm)

To create a new excel file, you need to use Microsoft Office Interop and do something like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Sheet 1 content";

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

To Insert data in the newly created excel do this:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
string sql = null;
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
MyConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('5','e')";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MyConnection.Close();
```

Comment: oh... sorry if forget description I'm not use Microsoft Office Interop. Do you have other way to create excel file.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without using any external library...The only thing i can think of is creating a csv file. I think that Excel would open it.

Comment: Another option would be to keep an empty excel file as a template, copy it to another file with the name you want and fill it with oledb. I think that would work too